# Change value of ng-model from popup windows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have input that generates dynamically by `ng-repeat`. for setting the value the user should click on the button and the popup windows will open. After selecting the value, the user will click on confirm button and I set the value by this code:

```
function SetLatLng() {
        if (!window.opener || window.opener.closed) {
          
            return;
        }

        var txtLat = window.opener.document.getElementById(latId);
        var txtLng = window.opener.document.getElementById(lngId);

     
        var lat = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
        var lng = document.getElementById('longitude').value;

        if (txtLat) {             
            window.opener.angular.element(txtLat).$rootScope().$apply(function () {
                window.opener.angular.element(txtLat).controller('ngModel').$setViewValue(lat);
            });
        }

        if (txtLng) {
            // Update the value of the ng-model attached to txtLng
            window.opener.angular.element(txtLng).$rootScope().$apply(function () {
                window.opener.angular.element(txtLng).controller('ngModel').$setViewValue(lng);
            });
        }

        window.close();
    }
```

The value of input visibly changes but the ng-model does not change. I also write a directive but it doesn't work either.

```
myapp.directive('setNgModelFromValue', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       
        if (!ngModel) return;
       
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
           
            ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
            ngModel.$render();
            return value;
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
           
            ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
            ngModel.$render();
            return value;
        });

        element.on('input', function () {
          
            scope.$apply(function () {
                var value = element.val();
                ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                ngModel.$render();
            });
        });
    }
};
```

});

I don't why It's not working. I also use `scope.$apply()` instead of `$rootScope().$apply` but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just find out I should trigger Input, it works great.

```
function SetLatLng() {
        if (!window.opener || window.opener.closed) {
            // Window has been closed or doesn't exist
            return;
        }

        var txtLat = window.opener.document.getElementById(latId);
        var txtLng = window.opener.document.getElementById(lngId);

        // Get the latitude and longitude values from the popup window
        var lat = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
        var lng = document.getElementById('longitude').value;

        if (txtLat) {
            // Update the value of the ng-model attached to txtLat
            window.opener.angular.element(txtLat).scope().$apply(function () {
                
                window.opener.angular.element(txtLat).controller('ngModel').$setViewValue(lat);
                
            });
            txtLat.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        }

        if (txtLng) {
            // Update the value of the ng-model attached to txtLng
            window.opener.angular.element(txtLng).scope().$apply(function () {
                window.opener.angular.element(txtLng).controller('ngModel').$setViewValue(lng);
            });
            txtLng.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        }

        window.close();
    }
```